# Using Bokeh to plot lat/long points with varying radii (varying size) and varying color based on values

Tags: python, plot, heatmap, bokeh

I have a code that produces a map of the united states with points at specified lat longs coordinates. Each of these points is tagged with a value that I want to use to indicate how large the point should be and what color the point should be. The code is below:

```
points = pd.read_csv(f)
lat = []
lon = []
heat = []
const = []

for i in range(points.shape[0]):
    lat.append(points.iat[i,0])
    lon.append(points.iat[i,1])
    heat.append(points.iat[i,2])
    const.append(points.iat[i,3])

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data = dict(
        lat = lat,
        lon = lon,
        radius = heat,
        constr = const,
        )
    )
TOOLS = 'box_zoom,wheel_zoom,hover'
state_xs = [states[code]["lons"] for code in states]
state_ys = [states[code]["lats"] for code in states]
p = figure(title="Bound Portfolio", toolbar_location="left",
       plot_width=1100, plot_height=700, tools = TOOLS)
p.patches(state_xs, state_ys, fill_alpha=0.3, fill_color = "orange",
      line_color="#884444", line_width=2, line_alpha=0.3)
circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=4.5, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.5, line_color=None)
#circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=4.5, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.5, line_color=None)
p.add_glyph(source, circle)
```

lat, lon, heat, and const are lists that I have created by reading the rows of a pandas dataframe. I want the values of heat (1-10) to be the radius of the point in question. I want each unique value in const to map to a unique color for the point in question. I have not been able to figure out how to make this code work. I have tried putting in many variations for the size of circle and it has not worked... the same applies for the color.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with unique alpha, color and size.
Key is to store values in a columndatasource then pass this as an argument into a figure method - i.e. `.circle("xname", "yname", source=source)`

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

lat = [0,1,2,3]
lon = [10,20,30,40]
radius = [1,2,3,4]
constr = [100,200,300,400]
colors= ['#014636', '#016c59','#02818a', '#3690c0']
alpha=[0.8,0.1,0.3,0.5]

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data = dict(
        lat = lat,
        lon = lon,
        radius = radius,
        constr = constr,
        colors=colors,
        alpha=alpha
        )
    )

p = figure(title="Bound Portfolio",
       plot_width=1100, plot_height=700)
p.circle("lon","lat",source=source, fill_alpha="alpha", fill_color = "colors",
      line_color="colors", line_width=2, line_alpha=0.3,radius="radius")
```